# How to get data from two tables from database?

Tags: mysql

Can you explain me, why this code not working?

```
SELECT SUM(`cash`) AS `cash`,COUNT(*) AS `rows` FROM `table_1` WHERE `login` = 'test' UNION ALL SELECT COUNT(*) AS `rows2` FROM `table_2` WHERE `login` = 'test';
```

In phpMyadmin I see this message:

> 1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

And I could not solve this problem.

Comment: Well, you have to take care that the result sets of both single queries are similar in structure, so that they can be combined to a single table. How else should the engine create a table from those two sets?

Comment: Hmm,ok but I'm a beginner in MySQL.

Comment: Can you show me an example code ?

Comment: The result of a `SELECT` query is a table, right? That result table has columns. Both result tables you want to combine have to have the same number and type of columns so that they can be combined. So the part between the `SELECT` and the `FROM` must define the same columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UNION takes the results of multiple SELECT statements and presents them as a single result set.  But in order to do this, the number of columns in the individual SELECT statements has to be the same.

To understand this, it may help to format the query a bit:

```
    SELECT
        SUM(`cash`) AS `cash`,
        COUNT(*) AS `rows`
    FROM `table_1`
    WHERE `login` = 'test'
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS `rows2`
    FROM `table_2`
    WHERE `login` = 'test'
```

Your first query is selecting two columns, *cash* and *rows*.  The second query only selects one column, *rows2*.  Also note that since UNION is concatenating the results, you may as well call the corresponding columns in each query by the same name.

If you really don't have any values that you want to select from the second table, you can substitute a default value for the missing columns:

```
    SELECT
        SUM(`cash`) AS `cash`,
        COUNT(*) AS `rows`
    FROM `table_1`
    WHERE `login` = 'test'
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        NULL AS `cash`
        COUNT(*) AS `rows`
    FROM `table_2`
    WHERE `login` = 'test'
```